# How to write in existing excel file using angular or node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am stuck actually i am working in a mean stack and i have a requirement in my project to write data in existing micros enable validated excel sheet. I do a lot of google but i did't find any node or angular module those are fulfill my requirement. Everyone given me option to create new file no one give me option update existing excel. Its really strange

**Below is my requirement step by step**

1. I have an micro enable excel (.xlsm)
2. Now i have to open it and write some data in angular or node js.
3. After that threw it to the user for download.

Please help me anyone

Answer (score 1):

The **SheetJS** API allow you convert Microsoft Excel (.xls / .xlsx) and OpenDocument (.ods) formats to JSON stream or files and import/export from/to MongoDB or MongooseJS. Just study the simple and easy API.

In Github you can find the documentation, tutorials and code examples.

**Site:** http://sheetjs.com/

**Project:** https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

**Interactive Demo:** http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/

Use the code example below, but just before run `npm install xlsx` and put the chunk of code to open the .xlsm file: `var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');`.

```
/* require XLSX */
var XLSX = require('xlsx')

function datenum(v, date1904) {
    if(date1904) v+=1462;
    var epoch = Date.parse(v);
    return (epoch - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data, opts) {
    var ws = {};
    var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
    for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
        for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
            if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
            if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
            if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
            if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
            var cell = {v: data[R][C] };
            if(cell.v == null) continue;
            var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

            if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
            else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
            else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
            }
            else cell.t = 's';

            ws[cell_ref] = cell;
        }
    }
    if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    return ws;
}

/* original data */
var data = [[1,2,3],[true, false, null, "sheetjs"],["foo","bar",new Date("2014-02-19T14:30Z"), "0.3"], ["baz", null, "qux"]]
var ws_name = "SheetJS";

function Workbook() {
    if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
    this.SheetNames = [];
    this.Sheets = {};
}

var wb = new Workbook(), ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);

/* add worksheet to workbook */
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;

/* write file */
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'test.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is everytime created a new .xls / .xlsx . My requirement is to append data into existing micro emabled excel (.xlsm) file. Actually have a excel so i just wanted to write data in it. Please suggest any more ??

Comment: Yes, you can! Read the docs. You can open the .xlsm file and update the cells of worksheet of a workbook and write the file.

I'll post a code example in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Currently office file is zip archive with xml files. So, in Node.js you can extract data by e.g. [`node-zip`](https://github.com/daraosn/node-zip), changed by e.g. [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) and zipped back.