# Edit a premade macro-enabled excel document from AngularJS webapp

Tags: angularjs, vba, excel

I've got quite the issue that I can't seem to figure out how to do cleanly after hours of scouring the internet, hoping you all could help me out.

We have an AngularJS web-app that is used to create an object in a database according a large set of variables. After the object is put into the database, we want to put some of the fields into a macro-enabled excel doc containing some necessary VBA macros that then downloads to the user's computer.

From what I've found, Angular can output the data to a new excel doc, but we need to have the data put into the pre-existing excel document. The closest tool I've found is [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) from a [different StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38639049/3081825), but that answer doesn't actually implement the functionality to edit the current excel, only write to a new excel document.

Any and all suggestions on fixing my problem are appreciated!

Comment: Ugh, I feel your pain.  I'm doing stuff like this at work. I personally would have Excel fetch the data directly form the data source (via ODBC), and create a new macro to copy the fetched data into your pre-existing excel document. If you have more hurdles with this approach, let's discuss further.

Comment: @AdamVincent there's definitely more hurdles. tl;dr, we have to take the sessionID from the web UI and pass it to the Excel workbook in order for any of the VBA service calls to work, as only an authenticated user can do the service calls and we're avoiding needing to login from the web UI and the workbook. we don't want to alter the back-end to allow an endpoint to access the sessionID without being authenticated, which is the major limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found an answer, but it's not quite available yet. I left [an issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/606) on the SheetJS GitHub page which got answered today. Sounds like macro persistence functionality is being added into the release this upcoming Friday. From there, add `bookVBA:true` to the options of your readFile call like `XLSX.readFile("filename", {bookVBA:true, /* .. other options */});`, and then on your writeFile call you add the option of `bookType:"xlsm"`.

This is of course speculatory, as the change isn't live yet. I'll make sure to update this answer at that time.

EDIT/UPDATE: SheetJS now works in copying over macros to a new workbook, but there's currently a bug. If you have any code in the ThisWorkbook object to do anything on startup, sheet changes, etc., they won't work after writing back out, as it creates a new ThisWorkbook1 object. I've already opened an issue on it, but that should be fixed relatively quickly.